# React Native - React Native Architecture

Tags: architecture, react-native, react-native-ios

Does **React Native** Application Development can be implement with Software Architecture such as **MVC, MVP, MVVM**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. React Native is just the "V" in those software design patterns you're mentioning. If you consider other libraries around React, like Flux, then *maybe* my answer isn't 100% accurate. I recommend reading this:

https://medium.com/javascript-inside/what-if-react-was-really-only-the-v-in-mvc-5854fd6f601c

Here's a more complete answer, considering the App not being just React Native but also the backend and the data models involved:

https://medium.com/of-all-things-tech-progress/understanding-mvc-architecture-with-react-6cd38e91fefd

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is, by using Redux or Relay Architecture

Answer (score 1):

react native is only view, but you can try to build your **MVC** Architecture.
here is my model you can use it as a model for your mvc Architecture.

[react-native-model](https://github.com/ziaadini/react-native-model)

Comment: It looks like the link isn't public :)

Answer (score 1):

Telescope is "A functional MVC framework for React"

Full disclosure - I wrote it.

It hasn't gained much notice but I think it has a lot going for it.

"Reduced boilerplate - Self-documenting syntax - Easy to test - Improved debugging - Data validation"

Its fully tested and I've used it in some big projects.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@idiosync/telescope